# Extract Host name, timestamp, HTTP request method, URI and protocol

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract Host name, timestamp, HTTP request method, URI and protocol from below responses

```
unicomp6.unicomp.net - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:06 -0400] "GET /shuttle/countdown/ HTTP/1.0" 200 3985
199.120.110.21 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:09 -0400] "GET /shuttle/missions/sts-73/mission-sts-73.html HTTP/1.0" 200 4085
```

using regular expressions. Please let me know how can I do this

Comment: It looks like  you analyzing log files What solutions have you tired so far? This site can give you a jumpstart if you haven’t tried anything yet.  https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below code

```
timestamp - r"\[\d+/\D+/.*\]
host name - (\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\s* |(.+)\.(com|info|biz|tv|net)
status code - "\s\d{3}
```

but not getting the desired result. It says expecting string or byte size

```
regex = r'\b(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\s* |(.+)\.(com|info|biz|tv|net)'

sample_text = ("[unicomp6.unicomp.net - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:06 -0400] "GET /shuttle/countdown/ HTTP/1.0" 200 3985, 199.120.110.21 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:09 -0400] "GET /shuttle/missions/sts-73/mission-sts-73.html HTTP/1.0" 200 4085]")

matches = re.findall(regex, sample_text)
hosts = []
for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    hosts.append(match.group()[1:27])
print(hosts)
```